# Java Docker API CPU Calculation

Tags: java, docker

i am using the Docker Java API and want to see the usage of the cpu.
But every time

`stats.getCpuStats().getCpuUsage().getPercpuUsage()` is null and i need it for the calculating. Does anybody know why it’s always null?

Code:

```
`float cpuPercent = 0.0f;

float cpuDelta = stats.getCpuStats().getCpuUsage().getTotalUsage().floatValue() - stats.getPreCpuStats().getCpuUsage().getTotalUsage().floatValue();
float systemDelta = stats.getCpuStats().getSystemCpuUsage().floatValue() - stats.getPreCpuStats().getSystemCpuUsage().floatValue();

if (cpuDelta > 0.0 && systemDelta > 0.0) {
    cpuPercent = (cpuDelta - systemDelta) * (stats.getCpuStats().getCpuUsage().getPercpuUsage().size() * 100F);
}`
```

I searched for other solutions but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the response is optimized for streams.
Your implementation expects only one result, therefore you need to set `withNoStream(true)` before `exec()` to normalize the values.

And, according to the documentation, to obtain a percentage of CPU use, it should be `(cpuDelta / systemDelta)`, not `(cpuDelta - systemDelta)`.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerStats

Answer (score -1):

The [Docker API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerStats) states:

> On a cgroup v2 host, the following fields are not set
>
> - `cpu_stats`: `cpu_usage.percpu_usage`

This is a low-level property of the host setup and not something your application can control at all.

You should still be able to get the total CPU usage and that's probably more useful for most applications.  The assignment of process threads to physical CPUs is managed by the Linux kernel and is somewhat arbitrary; it shouldn't usually matter which core you're running on.